# Teradata substring out of bounds

Tags: sql, substring, teradata

I'm having issues figuring out the bounds between a substring. For example for the string `063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_`I want to substring out `emshptea1`, but it also has to work for the string `063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_TESTDATA_HERE`.

Currently I have:

```
sel SUBSTR('063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_',POSITION('__' IN '063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_')+2,
    POSITION('_' IN  SUBSTR('063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_',POSITION('__' IN '063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_') + 2,CHARACTER_LENGTH('063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_') - (POSITION('__' IN '063016_shape_tea_cleanse__emshptea1_') + 2)))-1)
```

But that is erroring out due to it trying to substring 27 to -1.

Comment: so, do you want everything after `cleanse__` until the next `_`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a regular expression, this will extract everything between `__` and the following `_` or end of string:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '(?<=__).+?(?=(_|$))')
```

**'(?<= )'** is a look-behind, i.e search for previous characters without adding it to the result. Here: search for `__`

**'.+'** matches any character, one or multiple times. This would match until the end of the string ("greedy"), **'?'** ("lazy") prevents that.

**'(?= )'** is a look-ahead, i.e. search for following characters without adding it to the result.

**( | )** The pipe splits an expression in multiple alternatives. Here either an underscore character or the end of the string **$**

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you explain to me what all the symbols represent in the regexp?

Comment: @BobDunakey: Added some explanation. Regular Expressions are quite powerful, I only know the basics :)